# devIL causes program to be unable to start correctly

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, visual-studio-2010, devil

I just tried to use devIL and ULIT to help me with opengl texture loading. However, whenever the program starts, I get the error:

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

What happened? I'm using the Visual C++ 2010 RC, windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Any number of 10,000 things.  You're going to have to do some debugging of your own kiddo

Comment: Make the simplest, non-working program you can.  The problem may become obvious at this point.  If not, post the code.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if you attempt to run a 64-bit application, but Windows finds only the 32-bit version of some dependent DLL. You can fix this by making sure all the 64-bit dependency DLLs can be found by Windows, e.g. by setting %path% as appropriate.

Comment: Works for me! I had a 32-bit app that accidentally tried to use a 64-bit DLL. @Mark perhaps you copied over the wrong DLLs?