# Opencv 2.3 cvtColor function

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.3 with visual studio 2010 ultimate
the OpenCV works well with me, but when I call cvtColor function , I can't run the project
and this error dialogue appear

> "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). click OK
>   to close the application."

Comment: Is `cvtColor` the only non-working function? Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488123/devil-causes-program-to-be-unable-to-start-correctly). Most likely you are trying to use 32bit dlls in 64bit exe.

Comment: no there are many non-working function unfortunately , but what to do with the dlls ? the dlls of opencv is in it's folder bin-debug  and i had put the path of these dlls in the environment variable while i was setying-up opencv

Comment: [How to configure Visual Studio 2010 to use OpenCV 2.3 C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011238/opencv-2-3-c-visual-studio-2010/7014918#7014918)

Comment: @karlphillip  thank you , but i need the 64 bit steps , is it diffrent ?

Comment: Maybe the names of the libraries are , but the overall procedure is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right way to install the OpenCV 2.3 Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64 bit at "[Getting Started with OpenCV 2.3 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64-bit](http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/getting-started-with-opencv-2-3-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-in-windows-7-64-bit/#comment-411)".

Comment: [Using OpenCV 2.4.2 with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 (64-bit)](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is likely a missing DLL problem. The `cvtColor` function is contained in the `opencv_imgproc231.dll` library. You'll either need to place this DLL in the same directory as the executable, or append the OpenCV DLL path (e.g., `%OPENCV_ROOT%\install\bin`) to the `Path` variable. Also note, if you changed your `Path` variable while Visual Studio was open, you will need to restart Visual Studio for it to see the change.

If the above fails, and you used the binary distribution, consider rebuilding OpenCV from source. If a binary distribution was built for VS2008, it will not work with VS2010 and vice versa. [Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation) is a tutorial on how to build OpenCV from source on Windows.

Comment: the tutorial link you put ,all of it's steps have done with windows 32 bit , i hope it work with the 64 bit